# How to show rows data in **** format only last 3 digists

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Does Oracle provide a package or function for data masking ? For example, in a development environment, for data protection purposes, the information of the table customer needs to be masked.

```
create table customer (last_name varchar2(25), first_name varchar2(25), address varchar2(25));
insert into customer values('Doe', 'John', '10 someroad st');
```

In the production environment, if we do a select on customer, the result would be without any surprise:

```
select *
from customer;

LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME ADDRESS
-------------- -------------- --------------------
Doe John 10 someroad st
```

In the development environment, the same information needs to be masked for something like:

```
LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME ADDRESS
-------------- -------------- --------------------
Doe John 10 somerxxx st
```

Comment: Could you just insert junk-data into the dev tables instead of trying to transform them on select?

Comment: Display the data in SQL Query. Hide last 3 characters

Comment: Your example `Ahd Uiea 55 xxxx ue` does not show a result, where the last 3 characters from `Doe John 10 someroad st` are hidden... I don't understand what you expect in detail

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to mask data. I created a view.  You will need to adjust the regexp_replace to fit your needs

```
CREATE TABLE CARDS_TBL (
  CARD_ID NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  CARD_STR VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CARD_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4024007187788590');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5432223398564536');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5430445512530934');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4020156755227854');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5431248766892318');


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CARDS AS
  SELECT
    CARD_ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CARD_STR, '(^\d{3})(.*)(\d{4}$)', '\1**********\3') AS CARD_STR
  FROM CARDS_TBL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TBL_TRG_INSERT
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON CARDS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES (:NEW.CARD_STR);
END;
/

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES ('2222333344445555');

SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

UPDATE CARDS_TBL 
  SET CARD_STR = '2222333344445566'
  WHERE CARD_ID = 6;
/

SELECT * FROM CARDS;

CARD_ID    CARD_STR
1    402**********8590
2    543**********4536
3    543**********0934
4    402**********7854
5    543**********2318
6    222**********5566


SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

CARD_ID    CARD_STR
1    4024007187788590
2    5432223398564536
3    5430445512530934
4    4020156755227854
5    5431248766892318
6    2222333344445566
```